# What are all the weapons named after a boss?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

I need to know what every boss-named weapon. Can someone tell me what they are, and how to get them?

Comment: I answered your question but I'm curious. Why only the boss-named weapons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor SPOILERS ahead:

- [Twinbellows Cannon](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Twinbellows_Cannon) (complete chapter 1)
- [Gaol Blade](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Gaol_Blade) (complete chapter 2)
- [Hewdraw Club](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Hewdraw_Club) (complete chapter 3)
- [Great Reaper Palm](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Great_Reaper_Palm) (complete chapter 4)
- [Pandora Claws](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Pandora_Claws) (complete chapter 5)
- [Dark Pit Staff](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Dark_Pit_Staff) (complete chapter 6)
- [Thanatos Staff](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Thanatos_Staff) (complete chapter 7)
- [Kraken Arm](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Kraken_Arm) (complete chapter 8)
- [Phoenix Arm](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Phoenix_Arm) (complete chapter 10)
- [Cragalanche Cannon](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Cragalanche_Cannon) (complete chapter 11)
- [Arlon Orbitars](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Arlon_Orbitars) (complete chapter 13)
- [Phosphora Bow](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Phosphora_Bow) (complete chapter 14)
- [Magnus Club](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Magnus_Club) (complete chapter 18)